# How to design relational database which contains companies and simple customers

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema

I have to design a database schema, for the company which organizes conferences. In these conferences can participate private customers or other companies (each company can sign up few people). Currently, I need some bits of advice on how to keep previously mentioned customers in the DB. I thought about three ways:

1. Keep them in one table called `Customers` and for private customers leave fields empty (like company_name etc). I guess it is the worst idea.
2. Create two tables: `private_customer` and `company_customer`, but it seems that often those tables will be left joined, so it can cause performance issues.
3. Create one table for `customers`, and distinguish them by something like `customer_type`. Then create another table with customer types and so on. I guess it is the best option.
   @edit

For better understanding I will write the short summary:

*Some company organizes conferences (Each conference can take up to few days). Clients should registry to these conferences via www website. As a client we understand individual person or company, but participants of conferences are people(company can registry many people). The representative of the company can reserve many seats and supply information about participants two weeks before conference start date.*

I would appreciate every tip or other design. It would be nice if you could inform me about some sources about Designing Database Patterns as well.
Thanks in advance,

Mariusz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start by restating the requirements in more precise language.

- A conference has many participants.
- A conference has many clients.
- A client may be an individual attendee, or a delegate from a company.
- All participants are clients.
- Clients place reservations for 0 or more conferences.
- A client of type "company" may create a reservation for more than one participant.
- A client of type company may create reservations for known or unknown
  participants.
- All participants must be known 2 weeks before the
  conference start date.

(Unstated, but assumed)

- A client may place reservations for more than one conference.
- A client may place more than one reservation for a conference.
- An attendee may belong to more than one client over time (e.g. a single person might attend different conferences for several companies).

That leads to a schema along the following lines:

```
Conference
------------
ConferenceID (pk)
StartDate
EndDate

Client
---------
ClientID (PK)
ClientType (Company or Individual)

Reservation
------------
ClientID (FK)
ConferenceID (FK)
NumberOfAttendees 

ConferenceAttendee
-------------
AttendeeID (FK)
ClientID (FK)
ConferenceID (FK)
ConfirmationDate

Attendee
-------------
AttendeeID (PK)
```

You can then create checks that only clients of type "company" can place reservations for more than one attendee, that no ConferenceAttendee records are created with a confirmation date less than 2 weeks from the conference start date.

Answer (score 4):

The important idea is that organizations and individuals aren't identical, but they're not utterly unlike each other. Both can have names, addresses, and telephone numbers, and both can apparently participate in conferences.

There are various search terms for this kind of thing, including "exclusive arc" and "supertype/subtype".  I wrote this minimal example for PostgreSQL, but it's mostly standard SQL. (Syntax for automatic id numbers and for triggers varies a lot from dbms to dbms.)

The table "parties" is the supertype. The tables "inds" (individuals) and "orgs" (organizations) are the subtypes. Every party must be *either* an individual or an organization; a party can't be both, even by mistake. (This is *really* important.)

```
-- The "supertype". Attributes that apply to both individuals and to 
-- organizations go in this table.
--
create table parties (
    party_id serial primary key,
    party_type char(1) check (party_type in ('I', 'O')),
    party_full_name varchar(45) not null,

    -- This unique constraint lets foreign keys reference this pair
    -- of columns.
    unique (party_id, party_type)
);

-- For organizations, a "subtype" of parties. There's nothing special about
-- the column "ein". It's just an attribute that applies to organizations,
-- but doesn't apply to individuals.
--
create table orgs (
    party_id integer primary key,
    party_type CHAR(1) not null default 'O' check (party_type = 'O'),
    ein CHAR(10), -- In the USA, federal Employer Identification Number

    -- This reference to a pair of columns, together with the CHECK
    -- constraint above, guarantees that a row in this table will 
    -- reference an organization in "parties". It's impossible for 
    -- a row in this table to reference an individual.
    --
    foreign key (party_id, party_type) 
        references parties (party_id, party_type) on delete cascade
);

-- For individuals, a "subtype" of parties. There's nothing special about
-- the column "height_in" (height in inches). It's just an attribute that 
-- applies to individuals, but doesn't apply to organizations.
--
create table inds (
    party_id integer primary key,
    party_type char(1) not null default 'I' check (party_type = 'I'),
    height_in integer not null check (height_in between 24 and 108),

    -- See comments in "orgs" above.
    foreign key (party_id, party_type) 
        references parties (party_id, party_type) on delete cascade
);
```

Client code uses updatable views, not the base tables. Platforms vary in their support for updatable views. Most allow triggers on views, which is what I use below.

I've written a view for people below. The trigger handles only inserts. Code for updates and deletes is pretty similar. View and supporting code for organizations is also similar.

```
create view people as
select t1.party_id, t1.party_full_name, t2.height_in
from parties t1
inner join inds t2 on (t1.party_id = t2.party_id);

create or replace function insert_into_people() 
returns trigger as
$$
begin
    insert into parties (party_full_name, party_type)
    values (new.party_full_name, 'I');
    insert into inds (party_id, height_in) values (currval('parties_party_id_seq'), new.height_in);
    return null;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;

create trigger insert_people
instead of insert on people
for each row
execute procedure insert_into_people();
```

In production, you'd probably revoke permissions on the base tables from almost all users, and allow access only through the views. (And you *might* need more views.)

Since both individuals and organizations can participate in conferences, your table of conference participants would reference "parties"."party_id".

Answer (score 0):

> some sources about Desiging Database Patterns

You can see many example schemas at the [Database Answers](http://www.databaseanswers.org/) Data Models link.

The NIAM method led to ORM2 and FCO-IM. There's a [free online book on FCO-IM](http://www.fco-im.nl/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=47:fully-communication-oriented-information-modeling-&catid=35:books&Itemid=55). These methods understand that a relational table has an associated parmeterized statement about the application and holds the rows whose tuples make a true statement about the application from it.